# Eliminar elementos de un array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día, estoy tratando de eliminar un indice de un array de in input type file pero en la diferentes pruebas que he echo o me borra el primero o el ultimo aún usando `splice`.

```js
    var arrayFiles = [];
     $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {
    
         var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
         var array = (this.files.length);
         var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
         var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
         var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
         var numero = -1;
         if (extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
             if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                 //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
                 for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
                   var j = 0;
                     var reader = new FileReader();
                     var file = fileUpload.files[i]
                     reader.onload = function (e) {
                      numero++
                         image_holder.append("<div class='col-md-3 images'><img class='img-fluid img-thumbnail' height='500px' src='" + e.target.result + "'><i class='fas fa-times eliminar' data-borrar='"+ fileUpload.files[j].name.toLowerCase() +"'></i></div>")
                         j = j + 1;
                     }
                     image_holder.show();
                     reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
                     arrayFiles.push(file)
                    
                 }
    
             } else {
                 alert("Navegador no soporta  FileReader.");
             }
         } else {
             alert("Solo imagenes");
         }
         console.log(arrayFiles)
     });

    $(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function(event) {
      var elementoEliminar = $(this).data('borrar')
      alert(elementoEliminar)
      $(this).parent().remove();
      var elementoEliminado = arrayFiles.splice(elementoEliminar , 1);
      console.log(elementoEliminado)
      console.log(arrayFiles)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" multiple />
    <div id="image-holder" class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba pasar la posición a borrar en el array:

```
.....<i class='fas fa-times eliminar' data-borrar='"+ fileUpload.files[j].name.toLowerCase() +"' data-arraypos='" + i + "'>....

$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function(event) {
        var elementoEliminar = $(this).data('borrar');
        var elemPosicion = $(this).data('arraypos');
        alert(elementoEliminar);
        $(this).parent().remove();
        var elementoEliminado = arrayFiles.splice(elemPosicion , 1);
        console.log(elementoEliminado);
        console.log(arrayFiles);
        //actualizat posición después de borrar
       $(".eliminar").each(function(){
          int pos = $(this).data('arraypos');
          if (pos > elemPosicion){
             $(this).data('arraypos', pos-1);
           }
       });
});
```

Ver ejemplo de funcionamiento de [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp).

Comment: Hola @carmen
al hacerlo con la posición del array solo funciona en la primara ya que el las demás el indice cambia 
si antes era [0, 1, 2 ] y elimino el la posición 1 ahora es [0, 1]

Comment: Como necesitas el índice para borrar, lo que tendrás que hacer es modificar el atributo data-arraypos para los elementos restantes tras borrar, de modo  que siempre esté actualizado. Edito la respuesta para añadirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer encontré una solución mas fácil de lo que pensé pero si algunos expertos me podían decir si es viable

```
  $(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function(event) {
        var x = $(this).parent().index();
        var elementoEliminado = arrayFiles.splice(x , 1);
        console.log(elementoEliminado)
        console.log(arrayFiles)
        $(this).parent().remove();
 })
```

saludos!